# jqGrid XML data property load

Tags: jqgrid, xmlreader

I have a remote XML data generator which emits something like this:

```
<list>
  <hu.qualitis.opencms.utils.db.DBFile>
    <id>8dc66bf4-c39f-44c5-879d-1f3b16dc29be</id>
    <name>testfile.txt</name>
    ...
    <metadata>
      <property name="lines" value="5"/>
    </metadata>
  </hu.qualitis.opencms.utils.db.DBFile>
</list>
```

my definition of the xmlReader is as follows

```
xmlReader: { 
  root: "list",
  row: "hu\\.qualitis\\.opencms\\.utils\\.db\\.DBFile",
  repeatitems: false,
  id: "id"
},
```

This works OK.
My problem is about the **metadata** part which I cannot access. I tried things like:

```
colModel :[ 
  {name:'name', index:'name', width:60},
  ...
  {name:'metadata>property>lines', index:'name', width:10}
],
```

but to no avail.

Is it possible at all to configure the jqGrid XMLReader to read this value, or am I forced to change the generator?

**Update**

To sum up the responses: my original idea is not possible to implement.
The best solution would be to use JSON. This would be faster also.
An alternative solution is to modify the code which generates the XML. I will go with this, as all my communication is based on XML.
And another solution is to modify the XML with XSLT.

Comment: You should use JSON instead of XML is you want to read data which so far from the standard jqGrid input data. You can't read XML attributes in the jqGrid.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. All my grids use XML, so I won't bother making one single that uses JSON. So I have to change the generating code.

Comment: If you want to use XML you should hold the [XML format](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#xml_data) which jqGrid required. You can use XSLT for example to convert one XML file to another one. In any way XML based solution will be slowly as JSON based one.

Comment: I considered the options and the less complicated solutions for my case is changing the generating code.
Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You access attributes of nodes you need to specify the attribute name in square brackets [name] in the xmlmap of the colModel e.g.:-

for node

the name attribute of node property would require xmlmap:"metadata>property>[name]"

the value attribute of node property would require xmlmap:"metadata>property>[value]"